# How to manage section in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create an application with sections in my TableView.

But actually, I don't know how to manage sections.

I create sections and it works fine but when I try to add a new row in my section I got a problem.

Example:

> **I Create a new Item in my first section.**

[image]

> **The section name is "Aucun" and the rows label is going to set to "Test 1"**
>
> **It works!**

[image]

> **So, now I want to add something else**

[image]

> **The section name is "Produits Laitiers" and the row label is "Test2"**

[image]

> **FAIL :( The section is create but the row is not the good one**

There is my code for the moment

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arraySection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return arraySection[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfRowsInSection[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(String(describing: products[indexPath.row]["Name"]!))"
    cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)
    return cell!
}
```

> numberOfRowsInSection is an array of int where I store the number of products which have to be in this section.

Comment: What do you mean by creating a new row|section? Are you creating row|section dynamically?

Comment: Yep that's it. When the user entered something like in the screen I add sections/rows dynamically

Comment: You should take a look on this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html ?

Comment: @VictorSigler isn't help me... :(

Comment: Ok just give a moment to modulate an example for you quickly in code

Comment: @VictorSigler thanks :)

Comment: To implement sections you need either a nested array (outer array as sections, inner array as rows) or a custom struct representing the sections containing a name for the title and an array as rows

Comment: @pierreafranck See my anwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting "Test 1" each time, because you have sections, but you are always trying to get a value by using an index of a row without checking an index of a section:

```
\(String(describing: products[indexPath.row]["Name"]!))
```

If all your values for cells are storing in a single array, then you should get a value from an array by using the section number:

```
\(String(describing: products[indexPath.section]["Name"]!))
```

But this will work only if each section will have only one row. Otherwise you will have to get the number of section first to detect the section where current row is allocated and then get the number of row.

If you have an array of sections with array of rows for each section, that will look like this:

> let arraySection = [  [section #0 values],  [section #1 values],  ...
>   ]

Then you can get the value for each row by using this:

```
let value = arraySection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

========EDIT===========
But there is a much better way - use objects or structs

```
struct Row {
   var value: String = ""
}

struct Section {
  var name: String = ""
  var values: [Row] = []
}
```

So, using this structs, your code will be changed:

```
//your array of sections will contain objects
let arraySection: [Section] = [] 

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arraySection.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    //get the name of the section
    return arraySection[section].name
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //check the count of rows for each section
    return arraySection[section].values.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell")
     // now we can get the value for current row by checking sections and then rows
    cell?.textLabel?.text = arraySection[indexPath.section].values[indexPath.row].value
    cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. 

arraySection is already an array where I store my section name. 

Can you edit your answer with all the code plz? i'm very stuck :(

Comment: Check it. I wanna propose you another way to handle all values

Comment: Hmm, i don't understand the row struct's because you don't use it anywhere except in the cellForRowAt method, so I can use my actual dictionnary? Because i have not only ["Name"] store into it, I have 3 or 4 information that I'm going to use later

Comment: You can fill the Row or Section structs like you prefer. I mean you can store as many values in each struct as you need: timestamp, id etc. And you don't need to use dictionaries anymore. It is better because if you will make any mistake in dictionary key, you won't get data, structs won't allow you to make that mistake.

Comment: Ok thanks dude. I will try it and I will upvote asap :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the products array in the `UITableViewDataSource` method `cellForRowAt`. You are accessing the same array element for the first object in each section with

```
products[indexPath.row]["Name"]!
```

Probably you need to adjust your model to handle the `indexPath.section`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have 12 possible sections, i'm not going to create 12 arrays :/

Comment: Instead of using an array of dictionary objects, where you have to provide a key for each value, I would have a 2D Int array like [[Int]](). This way you can have an array of objects for each section. E.g [[1,2,3],[9,8,7]] where the first section rows can be populated with 1,2,3 and the second section with 9,8,7. i.e the cell for row method could use products[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I going to creates a `Section` model to keep track of the sections, like the following:

```
/// Defines a section in data source
struct Section {

   // MARK: - Properties

   /// The title of the section
   let title: String

   /// The items in the section
   var items: [String]
}
```

Then I going to use a `UITableViewController` with an **Add** right button to insert new section/rows to the `UITableView`, to add new sections/row I going to use a `UIAlertController` for the sake of brevity with two `UITextField`'s inside where you need to put the name of the section and the name of the row. At the end should look like the following image:

[image]

In case the section already exist is going to add the new row to the section, otherwise, is going to create the new section and row dynamically.

> **DynamicTableViewController**

```
class DynamicTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   // MARK: - Properties

   /// The data source for the table view
   var dataSource = [Section(title: "Section 1", items: ["Row 1"])]

   // MARK: - UIViewController

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   // MARK: - Table view data source

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return dataSource.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return dataSource[section].items.count
   }


   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
      cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
      return cell
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
      return dataSource[section].title
   }

   @IBAction func didTapAddButton(_ sender: Any) {
       presentAlerController()
   }
}

extension DynamicTableViewController {

   func add(_ sectionName: String?, _ row: String?) {

      guard let name = sectionName, let rowName = row,
        !name.isEmpty, !rowName.isEmpty else {
        return
      }

      if let index = dataSource.index(where: { $0.title == name }) {
          dataSource[index].items.append(rowName)
      } else {
         dataSource.append(Section(title: name, items: [rowName]))
      }

      tableView.reloadData()
   }

   func presentAlerController() {

      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add", message: "Add new Section/Row", preferredStyle: .alert)

      let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
          let sectionTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
          let rowTextField = alertController.textFields![1] as UITextField
          self?.add(sectionTextField.text, rowTextField.text)
      }

      let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in }

      alertController.addTextField { textField in
          textField.placeholder = "Add a new section name"
      }

      alertController.addTextField { textField in
          textField.placeholder = "Add a new row"
      }

      alertController.addAction(addAction)
      alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
      present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

In the above example, I'm not checking for the existence of duplicate row, you can do it is very easy. Also, I'm using the `reloadData()`, but you can use too if you want :

```
// insert the new section with row of the row in the existent section

tableView.beginUpdates()
// insert new section in case of any
insertSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
// insert new row in section using:
// insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Also you need to create a new `UIBarButtonItem` and connect it to the `@IBAction` I create it to be able to present the `UIAlertController` and add new section/row to the `UITableView`.

I hope this helps you.